# Python 3 + OpenCV + Mediapipe. Multiple target tracking

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tracking, mediapipe

I really don't quite understand all the Python ways yet (in fact... miles away).

I am using webcams to track a person.  Works quite well.

But, it randomly picks someone in the view and tracks them, sometimes hopping over to a different person and I am trying to iron that out.

I am not sure how it decides who to track, but my thinking is to identify individual targets (with a bounding box would be ideal), and then maybe ask it the then track the skeleton within that bounding box.

My code here is basically from lifting Googled code and tinkering around.  There are going to be errors!   But it does run and work.

Searched for a long time for a working example to try and copy, but have had no luck.

```
`import cv2
import mediapipe as mp                   # Controls the image/video processing
import serial                            # Serial for comms to the Arduino
import time                              # For delays etc
import platform                          # Details of the system we are running
import atexit                            # Clean method of exiting
import serial.tools.list_ports           # Serial port information
import sys
import numpy as np                       # Processes numbers, strings and arrays
import keyboard                          # Allows use of the keyboard
#import pickle                           # Allows you to store data

print(platform.system(), platform.release())
print("Python version " + platform.python_version())
print("")

mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils                                         # initialize Pose estimator
mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose

#mp_drawing_styles = mp.solutions.drawing_styles
#mp_holistic = mp.solutions.holistic                                             # Combines hands, pose and face meshes
#mp_face_mesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh                                           # Much more detailed face tracking

pose = mp_pose.Pose(
    min_detection_confidence=0.7,                                               # If confidence if >0.5, then start tracking
    min_tracking_confidence=0.7)                                                # If below min tracking, then go back to detection
    #static_image_mode = False                                                  # Whether to treat input images as static images or video stream - Default False
    #model_complexit = 1                                                        # Specify complexity of the pose landmark. 0, 1 or 2.  Default = 1
    #smooth_landmarks = True                                                    # Reduces jitter in the prediction.  Default is True

nvt_flag = False
bowflag = False
curtseyflag = False
showvideo = True
lux = 0
heartbeat = 0

pip_x_offset=50                                                                 # Position of the PIP
pip_y_offset=50

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

#---------------------  Arduino communications -----------------------

def findArduinoUnoPort():                                                       # Check all the comm ports for an Arduino
    portList = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
    for port in portList:
        if "VID:PID=2341:0043" in port[0]\
            or "VID:PID=2341:0043" in port[1]\
            or "VID:PID=2341:0043" in port[2]:
            print(port)
            print(port[0])
            print(port[1])
            print(port[2])
            return port[0]

def doAtExit():
    if serialUno.isOpen():
        serialUno.close()
        print("Close serial")
        print("serialUno.isOpen() = " + str(serialUno.isOpen()))

atexit.register(doAtExit)

unoPort = findArduinoUnoPort()
if not unoPort:
    print("No Arduino found")
    sys.exit("No Arduino found - Exiting system")

print("Arduino found: " + unoPort)
print()

serialArduino = serial.Serial(unoPort, 9600,timeout=0)
print("serialUno.isOpen() = " + str(serialArduino.isOpen()))


#------------------ Camera input selection -----------

header = cv2.imread("header.png")                                                                       # Create the header page
cv2.putText(header, 'SELECT VIDEO SOURCE', (30,310), font, 1, (0, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)             # Text (frame, Text, pos, font, color, thickness)
cv2.putText(header, '1: Internal webcam', (30,360), font, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)
cv2.putText(header, '2: External webcam', (30,410), font, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)
cv2.putText(header, '3: Local video file', (30,460), font, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)
cv2.putText(header, '4: External IP camera (no password)', (30,510), font, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)
cv2.putText(header, '5: External IP camera (Password protected)', (30,560), font, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)
cv2.imshow('Output', header)
cv2.waitKey(300)

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)                                                       # Laptop built-in webcam
        vsource = 1  
        break;

    elif keyboard.is_pressed('2'):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)                                        # External USB camera
        vsource = 2
        break;

    elif keyboard.is_pressed('3'):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('dance2.mp4')                                            # Read local video file
        vsource = 3
        break;

    elif keyboard.is_pressed('4'):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://192.168.1.64/1')                                 # Capture from an IP camera
        vsource = 4
        break;


    elif keyboard.is_pressed('5'):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.64/1')               # Capture from an IP camera with password + username
        vsource = 5
        break;

cv2.waitKey(10)
cv2.putText(header, 'Source ' + str(vsource) +' selected', (30,610), font, 1, (255, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)      # Selected source
cv2.imshow('Output', header)   
cv2.waitKey(300)

serialArduino.write(str.encode('4'))                                            # Tell the Arduino we DO have a valid track (might get cancelled immediatley in the loop)

#------------------  Start the main camera routine -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

while cap.isOpened():                                                           # read frame from capture object
    _, frame = cap.read()

    width = 1280                                                                # Resize the webcam feed
    height = 720
    dim = (width, height)
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)


#--------- Heartbeat Serial data to Arduino -----------------

    heartbeat += 1

    if heartbeat>50 and nvt_flag == False:
        heartbeat = 0
        serialArduino.write(str.encode('4'))                                    # Tell the Arduino we DO have a valid track.  (Pulse is checked on the Arduino)

#-------- Check the camera feed. Is there a target? ---------
    try:
        RGB = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)                            # convert the frame to RGB format

        results = pose.process(RGB)                                             # process the RGB frame to get the result

        black = cv2.imread("black.png")                                         # Create a blank page for the 'video off' feed

        #print(results.pose_landmarks)                                          # Print the co-ords of ALL the skeleton landmarks

        if showvideo == True:                                                   # Show live video feed
            mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(                                                           # draw detected skeleton on the frame  (MP stands for mediapipe)
                frame, results.pose_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
                mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(0,0,255), thickness=5, circle_radius=1),           # Definition of the landmark circles (B G R)
                mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(255,255,255), thickness=2, circle_radius=1)        # Definition of the joining lines (B G R)
                )
        else:                                                                   # Draw black background
            mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(                                                           # draw detected skeleton on the frame  (MP stands for mediapipe)
                black, results.pose_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
                mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(0,0,255), thickness=5, circle_radius=1),           # Definition of the landmark circles (B G R)
                mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(255,255,255), thickness=2, circle_radius=1)        # Definition of the joining lines (B G R)
                )

        for id, lm in enumerate(results.pose_landmarks.landmark):               # Create a for loop to identify each skeleton joint
            h, w, c = frame.shape
            #print(id, lm)                                                      # Print ALL the skeleton joint position values

            if (id == 0):                                                       # Identify the nose
                cx0, cy0 = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)                         # Calculate the actual pixel value
                nose = cy0
                cv2.circle(frame, (cx0, cy0), 10, (255,0,0),3)                  # Larger round target on the nose

                if showvideo == False:
                    cv2.circle(black, (cx0, cy0), 20, (255,0,0),3)              # Larger round target on the nose
                    cv2.circle(black, (cx0, cy0), 40, (255,0,0),3)              # Larger round target on the head

            if (id == 11):                                                      # Identify the left shoulder
                cx11, cy11 = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)                       # Calculate the actual pixel value
                lshoulder = cy11
                cv2.circle(frame, (cx11, cy11), 10, (0,255,0),3)                # Larger round target on the L shoulder
                cv2.circle(black, (cx11, cy11), 10, (0,255,0),1)                # Larger round target on the L shoulder

            if (id == 12):                                                      # Identify the right shoulder
                cx12, cy12 = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)                       # Calculate the actual pixel value
                rshoulder = cy12
                cv2.circle(frame, (cx12, cy12), 10, (0,255,0),3)                # Larger round target on the R shoulder
                cv2.circle(black, (cx12, cy12), 10, (0,255,0),3)                # Larger round target on the R shoulder

            if (id == 25):                                                      # Identify the left knee
                cx25, cy25 = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)                       # Calculate the actual pixel value
                lknee = cy25
                cv2.circle(frame, (cx25, cy25), 10, (0,255,255),3)              # Larger round target on the left knee
                cv2.circle(black, (cx25, cy25), 10, (0,255,255),3)              # Larger round target on the left knee

            if (id == 26):                                                      # Identify the right knee
                cx26, cy26 = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)                       # Calculate the actual pixel value
                rknee = cy26
                cv2.circle(frame, (cx26, cy26), 10, (0,255,255),3)              # Larger round target on the right knee
                cv2.circle(black, (cx26, cy26), 10, (0,255,255),3)              # Larger round target on the right knee

            if (id == 23):                                                      # Identify the left hip
                cx23, cy23 = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)                       # Calculate the actual pixel value
                lhip= cy23
                cv2.circle(frame, (cx23, cy23), 10, (0,255,255),3)              # Larger round target on the left hip
                cv2.circle(black, (cx23, cy23), 10, (0,255,255),3)              # Larger round target on the left hip
            
            if (id == 24):                                                      # Identify the right hip
                cx24, cy24 = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)                       # Calculate the actual pixel value
                rhip = cy24
                cv2.circle(frame, (cx24, cy24), 10, (0,255,255),3)              # Larger round target on the right hip
                cv2.circle(black, (cx24, cy24), 10, (0,255,255),3)              # Larger round target on the right hip

            if (id == 31):                                                      # Identify the left foot
                cx31, cy31 = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)                       # Calculate the actual pixel value
                lfoot = cy31
                cv2.circle(frame, (cx31, cy31), 10, (255,0,255),3)              # Larger round target on the left foot
                cv2.circle(black, (cx31, cy31), 10, (255,0,255),3)              # Larger round target on the left foot
            
            if (id == 32):                                                      # Identify the right foot
                cx32, cy32 = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)                       # Calculate the actual pixel value
                rfoot = cy32
                cv2.circle(frame, (cx32, cy32), 10, (255,0,255),3)              # Larger round target on the right foot
                cv2.circle(black, (cx32, cy32), 10, (255,0,255),3)              # Larger round target on the right foot


#---------------- Target distance & height --------------------
                
        if (lfoot-nose)>(rfoot-nose):                                           # Height in pixels calculation (foot to nose)
            height = lfoot-nose
        else:
            height = rfoot-nose                                                 # CURRENTLY NOT USING THIS CALC

        width = cx11-cx12                                                       # Live reported width of the shoulders in pixels

        focallength = (320 * 1000) / 280                                        # Work out the focal length (320 is between the shoulders in pixels)  1000mm is the inital setup distance
                                                                                # 280mm is the measured width of the shoulders at 1000mm

        livedistance  = (280 * focallength) / width                             # Therefore, work out the live range to target
  
        if showvideo == True:
            cv2.putText(frame, 'Distance to target: ' + str(int(livedistance)) + ' mm', (20,70), font, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_4)
        else:    
            cv2.putText(black, 'Distance to target: ' + str(int(livedistance)) + ' mm', (20,70), font, 1, (0, 0 , 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)




            if showvideo == True:
                frame[pip_y_offset:pip_y_offset+resize_img.shape[0], pip_x_offset:pip_x_offset+resize_img.shape[1]] = resize_img    # Display the respect image PIP
                cv2.putText(frame, 'Live video mode', (20,30), font, 1, (0, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4) 
                cv2.putText(frame, 'TEST MODE', (300,30), font, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)
                cv2.imshow('Output', frame)
                
            if showvideo == False:             
                black[pip_y_offset:pip_y_offset+resize_img.shape[0], pip_x_offset:pip_x_offset+resize_img.shape[1]] = resize_img    # Display the respect image PIP
                cv2.putText(black, 'Masked video mode', (20,30), font, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)
                cv2.putText(black, 'TEST MODE', (360,30), font, 1, (0, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)
                cv2.imshow('Output', black)

#------------ Toggle video mode ---------------------------------


        if keyboard.is_pressed('v') and showvideo == True:
                showvideo = False
                while keyboard.is_pressed('v'):
                    cv2.waitKey(1)
                
        if keyboard.is_pressed('v') and showvideo == False:
                showvideo = True
                while keyboard.is_pressed('v'):
                    cv2.waitKey(1)

        if showvideo == True:
            cv2.putText(frame, 'Live video mode', (20,30), font, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_4)               # Text (frame, Text, pos, font, color, thickness)
            cv2.imshow('Output', frame)                                                                       # Display the live video feed (window name, image)
        else:
            cv2.putText(black, 'Masked video mode', (20,30), font, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)             # Text (frame, Text, pos, font, color, thickness)
            cv2.imshow('Output', black)                                                                       # Display the blank background image

#------------ tracking online Y/N --------------
            
        if nvt_flag == True:                                                    # Reset the no valid target flag
            #serialArduino.write(str.encode('4'))                                # Tell the Arduino we DO have a valid track
            print("Tracking online")
            nvt_flag = False
            
    except:
        serialArduino.write(str.encode('5'))                                    # Tell the Arduino we do NOT have a valid track
        if nvt_flag == False:
            print("No valid target")
            nvt_image = cv2.imread("nvt.png")                                   # Create the no valid target image
            cv2.imshow('Output',nvt_image)                                      # Display the no valid target image  
            nvt_flag = True                                                     # Set the tracking error message flag
        #break                                                                  # Disable the frame draw error break
            
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        print("Exit routine") 
        break
    
cap.release()                                                                   # Closes the video window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```